# Failed to read from properties file

Tags: java, unix, properties, jar

I have a java application which works fine when ran in eclipse and when ran from the jar directly.

The error "Failed to read from properties file" occurs when a class(1.class) in my jar(1.jar) is accessed from another class(2.class) in another jar(2.jar), which inturn is called from a shell script. I tried displaying the classpath in the script and the path where I have put the properties file is added to the class path. Any idea why?

Shell script --> 2.jar - 2.class --> 1.jar - 1.class

Comment: Where's the properties file? In the 1.jar or on the file system?

Comment: can it be a permission issue ? also, are you sure the path it goes to is correct ?

Comment: Care to share some code?

Comment: I suspect the properties file is not where your program expects it to be.

Comment: Properties file is in the same directory where i have put 1.jar
Yes, the path goes correct

Comment: Code to read properties file:
`String PROP_FILE = "./" + Constants.PROP_FILE_NAME;Properties prop = new Properties();
   file = new FileInputStream(PROP_FILE);
   prop.load(file);`

Comment: Can you have a try prop.load(2.class.getResouceAsStream(Constants.PROP_FILE_NAME));

Comment: I can't change anything in 2.class. The real issue is the placement of properties file i suspect, as it works when a class from my jar is directly invoked (i.e any class from 1.jar)